# Sorting data frame according to year and month

Tags: python, pandas

I have bitcoin historical data. I split the **"DATE"** Colum as **"year month days and hour"** because I wanted to sort data based on hours["AS it is hourly base data"]. the data goes up to 2021-12 ie Decmber["the dates goes from 1 to 30 every month"]. I want to sort this data further as:-    **"2019-Jan, 2020-Jan 20201-Jan" then "2019-Feb,2020-Feb, 2021-Feb"** and soon on

| Year | Month | DAy | Hour | open | high | low | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3700.05 | 3725.58 | 3698.83 | 3715.09 |
| 2019 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3700.05 | 3725.58 | 3698.83 | 3715.09 |
| 2019 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 3700.05 | 3725.58 | 3698.83 | 3715.09 |
| 2019 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 3700.05 | 3725.58 | 3698.83 | 3715.09 |
| 2019 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 3700.05 | 3725.58 | 3698.83 | 3715.09 |

can this be done by saying I have split the "DATE" column? if YES please any suggestion on how this can be achieved

The original **"DATE"** colum was as follows :- **2019-01-01T00:00:00Z**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first sort with respect to `Month` and then `Year`:

```
>>> df.sort_values(["Month", "Year"], ignore_index=True)

   Year  Month  DAy  Hour     open     high      low    close
0  2019      1    1     0  3700.05  3725.58  3698.83  3715.09
1  2020      1    1     0  3700.05  3725.58  3698.83  3715.09
2  2019      2    1     0  3700.05  3725.58  3698.83  3715.09
3  2020      2    1     0  3700.05  3725.58  3698.83  3715.09
4  2019      3    1     0  3700.05  3725.58  3698.83  3715.09
```

(changed your dataframe to show 2020 too).

Comment: But this doesn't sort it as 2019jan 2020jan 2021jan and so on.  it just does 2019 Jan, Feb......till December also for 2020 and 20201. I don't want to sort like that.

Comment: @HemanthGirimath First row is "2019, 1" second row is "2020, 1", so it is sorting like 2019jan, 2020jan, isn't it?

Comment: @HemanthGirimath I added a `reset_index` to have the numbers at the left go as 0,1,.... Maybe that caused the impression that it is not sorting. What do you say now?

Comment: hi @HemanthGirimath, does it work now? If not, can you please provide feedback so the answer can be improved or removed altogeher?

Comment: sorry for the late reply I just wanted to make sure. Yes, it did work ty for the time and advice. but I don't get it how does just using sort_values did the work, can u please explain it to me. I have been thinking about how to achieve this for the past 2 days and it was so simple. df.sort_values(["Month", "Year"]).reset_index(drop=True) this line of code has no condition for anything does it by default do it ?

Comment: When we give `["Month", "Year"]` to it, it first sorts them by `Month`. Therefore all the Januaries come first, all the feburaries next and so on. We then tell it to sort the rest using the `Year` so 2019 comes before 2020 and so on. In other words, "look at months to sort; but if two values have the same month, then sort according to their year". @HemanthGirimath

Comment: @HemanthGirimath `reset_index` at the end resets the index after sorting so that it increases from 0 to length minus 1, i.e., 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. This step is optional, up to you.

Comment: ["Month", "Year"] ok so it does it by default :) I didn't know that :(  finally, I get it. once again very thank full to you

Comment: @HemanthGirimath 
glad to be of help! If you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved.